# How to retreive a list of custom objects from Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am sending to a Firebase document a list of Game() objects that i want later to retreive, but i cant seem to find how i can do that.
This is the Game object:

```html
@Parcelize
data class Game(
    var id: String? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var imageUrl: String? = null,
    var minPlayers: Int? = null,
    var maxPlayers: Int? = null,
    var playTime: Int? = null
) : Parcelable
```

This is how i write to Firebase:

```html
private fun dbNewSession() {

        db.collection(sessionTargetDocument)
            .add(
            //another custom class
                Session(
                    participants = listOf(mapOf(userId to false)),
                    user = userId,
                )
            )
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                sessionId = documentReference.id
           //  this is where i add the list of Game() 
db.collection(sessionTargetDocument).document(sessionId).collection("games").document("filtered_games")
                    .set(mapOf("filtered_games" to gameList))
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e)
            }
    }
```

[Image of the firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DDkW.jpg)

How can i retreive the game list back in to List form ?

Comment: I just answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395151/how-to-read-data-from-nested-array-in-firestore/70401994#70401994). Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for your response but that way was the first thing I tried. I can't make it work that way. What I ended up doing is iterating through the list of maps and then asigning the values to an Game object that is added then to the list. I believe that is not the best way to go, but... I am glad it works.

Comment: What exactly didn't work?